# Solution of Riccati system of ODEs

Tags: reference-request, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, differential-equations

We have following equation:
$$
w(t,v) = \exp\Bigl(-\phi (t) \frac{v^2}{2}-\psi (t) v -\chi (t)\Bigr),\quad (t,v)\in [0,T]\times \mathbb{R},
$$
where $(\phi, \psi ,\chi)$ are solutions of the Riccati system of ODEs:
$$
\begin{cases}
\dot{\phi}-2\bar{\kappa}\phi -\nu^2 (1-\rho^2)\phi^2 +\lambda^2 =0,& \phi(T)=0,\\
\dot{\psi} - (\bar{\kappa}+\nu^2 (1-\rho^2)\phi )\psi +\kappa \theta\phi = 0,& \psi (T)=0,\\
\dot{\chi}+\kappa\theta\psi -\frac{\nu^2}{2}(-\phi + (1-\rho^2)\psi^2)=0,& \chi(T)=0,
\end{cases}
$$
Can someone give a reference to this Riccati systems? Is this example wide known?

**Edit:** this was found in https://arxiv.org/pdf/2006.01496.pdf on page 36

Comment: Is there any context to this question ? Where did you get them from ?

Comment: thanks for asking, I've added a reference

Comment: Hmm.  https://arxiv.org/pdf/2006.01496.pdf  has only 26 pages.

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear if the data $\theta, \kappa,\lambda,\nu,\rho$ are also some functions of $t$ or just constants. The system does not seem to be of a particularly wide known type or relevant *per se*; in any case, it has a triangular form, and one can solve the three equations in order as scalar ODE's, by the usual reduction to linear equations. Specifically, the solution $\phi$ of the first Riccati equation can be written $\phi(t)=\frac{y(t)}{x(t)}$ for a solution of the linear system
$$\bigg[{ x \atop y}\bigg]'=\bigg[{ 0\atop -\lambda^2} \quad{-\nu^2(1-\rho^2)\atop 2\bar\kappa}\bigg]\bigg[{ x \atop y}\bigg]
$$ with initial conditions
$$\bigg[{ x(T) \atop y(T)}\bigg] = \bigg[{1 \atop 0}\bigg].
$$
Then $\psi$ solves a linear equation where $\phi$ enters as coefficient, and $\chi$ is the anti-derivative of a combination of $\phi$ and $\psi$.